# BestNormalize gives misleading results?

Tags: variables, normalization, predict

I am wondering why I get different results every time I run this code:

```
# arcsinh transformation
(arcsinh_obj <- arcsinh_x(df$Var1))
# Box Cox's Transformation
(boxcox_obj <- boxcox(df$Var1))
# Yeo-Johnson's Transformation
(yeojohnson_obj <- yeojohnson(df$Var1))
# orderNorm Transformation
(orderNorm_obj <- orderNorm(df$Var1))
# Pick the best one automatically
(BNobject <- bestNormalize(df$Var1))
# Last resort - binarize
(binarize_obj <- binarize(df$Var1))

summary(df$Var1)
xx <- seq(min(12), max(56), length = 295)

plot(xx, predict(arcsinh_obj, newdata = xx), type = "l", col = 1, ylim = c(-4, 4),
     xlab = 'df$Var1', ylab = "g(df$Var1)")
lines(xx, predict(boxcox_obj, newdata = xx), col = 2)
lines(xx, predict(yeojohnson_obj, newdata = xx), col = 3)
lines(xx, predict(orderNorm_obj, newdata = xx), col = 4)

legend("bottomright", legend = c("arcsinh", "Box Cox", "Yeo-Johnson", "OrderNorm"), 
       col = 1:4, lty = 1, bty = 'n')

par(mfrow = c(2,2))
MASS::truehist(arcsinh_obj$x.t, main = "Arcsinh transformation", nbins = 100)
MASS::truehist(boxcox_obj$x.t, main = "Box Cox transformation", nbins = 100)
MASS::truehist(yeojohnson_obj$x.t, main = "Yeo-Johnson transformation", nbins = 100)
MASS::truehist(orderNorm_obj$x.t, main = "orderNorm transformation", nbins = 100)

par(mfrow = c(1,2))
MASS::truehist(BNobject$x.t, 
               main = paste("Best Transformation:", 
                            class(BNobject$chosen_transform)[1]), nbins = 100)
plot(xx, predict(BNobject, newdata = xx), type = "l", col = 1, 
     main = "Best Normalizing transformation", ylab = "g(x)", xlab = "x")

dev.off()
boxplot(log10(BNobject$oos_preds), yaxt = 'n')
axis(2, at=log10(c(.1,.5, 1, 2, 5, 10)), labels=c(.1,.5, 1, 2, 5, 10))
```

I even tried this every time I was re running the analysis in case his was actually affecting

```
 rm(list = ls())
```

Could you please give me a hand?

Thanks 
lil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely getting different results because the `bestNormalize()` function uses repeated cross-validation (and doesn't automatically set the seed), so the results will be slightly different each time that's run.

Try setting the seed (e.g. `set.seed(3)`).

Or, you can tell the function not to perform repeated CV by setting `out_of_sample = FALSE`, or use leave-one-out CV by setting `loo = TRUE`.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know this!
Thanks!!